# problems in my list sorting code in python

Tags: python, list

I've come up with this code to sort out duplicates in a randomly arranged list of numbers.

```
counter = 0
randomDup_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 0, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 4]
dup_sorted = []
for x in randomDup_list:
    if len(randomDup_list) == 0:
        dup_sorted.append(x)
        counter +=1
    elif x != randomDup_list[counter]:
        for y in dup_sorted:
            if y != x:
                dup_sorted.append(x)
print(dup_sorted)
```

When I run the code there are no errors but the numbers don't seem to be appending to my new list, and it comes out blank like this: `[]`.

Comment: What is your expected output from `randomDup_list` this list?

Comment: There are various types of sorting algorithms.  Can you mention which type is this?  I don't quite follow the fogic.  For instance what is the purpose of `if len(randomDup_list) == 0:` in the for loop?

Comment: In the `elif` case: `dup_sorted` is empty at the beginning so `.append()` is never called.

Comment: sorry if some of my messy code is confusing, but ```if len(randomDup_list) == 0:``` is just to see if the new list is empty so you dont have to check for duplicates for the first number and just append it straight away. it kinda made sense to me when i first wrote the code.

Comment: as for my expected output, my teacher wanted us to remove any duplicates from the list without changing the order or sorting the list first. so for this list the output should be [0, 3, 1, 9, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way to do this is with a list comprehension, like so:

```
dup_sorted = [el for index, el in enumerate(randomDup_list) if el not in randomDup_list[:index]]
```

Enumerate will create a list of tuples with the first tuple element as the index in the list, `[(0,0), (1,3), (2,0), ...]` are the first 3 elements in your case.

Then it basically checks if `el` is the first occurence of `el` in the list and if it is, it adds `el` to the `dup_sorted` list.

List comprehensions are maybe hard to understand, but there is plenty of information about them on the internet. Good luck with learning Python!

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you want but you can basically sort the list like that

```
print(sorted(randomDup_list))
```

and you can create your new list like that

```
dup_sorted = sorted(randomDup_list)
print(dup_sorted)
```

Comment: im so sorry i should have specified, but my teacher doesnt want us to sort the list in ascending order. he wanted us to figure out a way to get rid of duplicates without changing the order of any of the numbers in the list. my bad!

Comment: If you want just to get rid of duplicated you can use ```numpy.unique()```

Answer (score 0):

Hey welcome to learning python. I have been coding for a couple of years but I still use `print` to test my logic.

Lets break down your code and add `print` to each logic test

```
counter = 0
randomDup_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 0, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 4]
dup_sorted = []
for x in randomDup_list:
    print("start iteration")
    if len(randomDup_list) == 0:
        print("1 true")
        dup_sorted.append(x)
        counter +=1
    elif x != randomDup_list[counter]:
        print("2 true")
        print(dup_sorted)
        for y in dup_sorted:
            if y != x:
                print("3 true")
                dup_sorted.append(x)
    print("stop iteration")
print(dup_sorted)
```

If you run this code you will see that the first logic test will never be true in your example. So it will go to the second logic test. This will eventually evaluate to true but there will be some iterations that will be skipped. Blank blocks of `start iteration stop iteration`. For the last logic test this will never be true because dup_sorted will always be empty. So `for y in dup_sorted` will result to nothing.

Also I think `sort out` is ambiguous. Is it sort? filter?

You can do `set(randomDup_list)` for filtering out duplicates
You can do `sorted(randomDup_list)` for sorting out the list
You can do `sorted(list(set(randomDup_list))` for a sorted filtered list

Seeing your new comments

```
randomDup_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 0, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 4]
dup_sorted = []
for x in randomDup_list:
    if x in dup_sorted:
        continue
    else:
        dup_sorted.append(x)
print(dup_sorted)
```

This initializes an empty list. Loops through your list. Check if it exists then appends if not. Since List maintain order, you can expect the order not to change.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any duplicates from the list without changing the order

**Code**

```
dup_sorted = []
for x in randomDup_list:
  if not x in dup_sorted:  # check if x is in output yet
    dup_sorted.append(x)   # add x to output
  
print(dup_sorted)
# Output: [0, 3, 1, 9, 8, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
counter = 0
randomDup_list = [0, 3, 0, 1, 9, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 0, 6, 5, 2, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 4]
dup_sorted = []


dup_sorted.append(randomDup_list[0])
for x in range(len(randomDup_list)):
    temp = 0
    for y in range(len(dup_sorted)):
        if randomDup_list[x] != dup_sorted[y]:
            temp = temp + 1
    if temp == len(dup_sorted):
        dup_sorted.append(randomDup_list[x])
        
print(dup_sorted)
```